# How to analyse periodic data obtained from a vibration experiment?

Tags: fft

I have data from a vibration experiment on a structure. This data was obtained by attaching an accelerometer to a FFT analyser, which records the data at a high sampling rate (typically in kHz range) and can also perform real-time FFT of the recorded data.

[image: sample signal and its FFT]

The image above shows the recorded signal below and the FFT above. The FFT shows all the dominant frequencies in the original signals.

What more patterns/ important data points can I discern from this data, that might have utility ?

For example, one being, the RMS value of the signal. What else ?

Also, the recorded data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9fbkDTtTJfSblh3b0c2OXBYYzA/view?usp=sharing) as a mat file, which can be loaded in matlab, the data in a variable called Track1.

The physics of the problem: The data is collected from a shake table, a rigid platform, that oscillates back and forth, so the sharp edges in the original signal periodically, representing the point of return.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that you are observing a system (the structure) driven by an input (shake table).  Assuming linearity, the FFT result was caused by the shake table *and* the structure.  You should be able to pick out the various components to identify mechanical resonances in the structure.  For instance, you should see a strong component at the frequency of the shake table.  Exactly how to do this in more detail is out of my domain, as I am an electrical, not mechanical, engineer.

Comment: I would eventually put an accelerometer on a structure, which would be fastened to the shake table, the results above are for accelerometer attached directly to shake table. So, ideally i should see a sinusoid on the lower graph (i.e a - t graph) and a single peak in the fft, at the frequency of excitation, but our shake table seems to be a sum of several frequencies. What other patterns / data-point are discernible from the data above ?

Comment: A quick question Chintan. In the time domain, is the acceleration of the shake table sinusoidal or more like a square wave?

Comment: If there is an input signal, then you could look at [this document](http://cstwiki.wtb.tue.nl/images/FRF_measurement.pdf) in order to construct a transfer function.